# How to run JetBrains WebStorm refactoring 'change ES6 import' for the whole project

Tags: typescript, refactoring, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

After refactoring a project, some files were moved to another npm package and after that source files changed to re-export them from a new place (to minimize migration effort).

After some time I did notice useful refactoring named 'Change ES6 import' which allows to change import from re-exported type to original:

[image]

It is possible to run it in a batch for all files in the project? Is there another refactoring/way to do that?

Comment: I do not think it is possible, Fix All is only supported for inspections not intentions. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206886125/comments/360000724419

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open project tree. Usually it's `Alt + 1` key combination.
2. Select required folder and open context menu (mouse right btn click).
3. Select `Reformat code` option (`Ctrl + Alt + L`) or `Optimize imports` (`Ctrl + Alt + O`).

Comment: unfortunatelly, this method cannot run required refactoring

Comment: Maybe, you should write your own script or use `sed` utility to replace text in files